# RichTextBox scrollbar keeps jumping back to top/flickering

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want the scrollbar to always be at the bottom, but whenever I try that, it's like jumping back to the top and then goes to the bottom, how do I stop or prevent this?
This is the code I have so far:

```
rtbOutputText.SelectionStart = rtbOutputText.Text.Length;
rtbOutputText.ScrollToCaret();
```

Also, when I select text in the richtextbox is spacing, going up and down, selecting stuff I'm not selecting...

Comment: what event/function did you pull your code snippet from

Comment: @MarkHall I update the text from via timer.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add rtbOutputText.SelectionLength = 0 before SelectionStart.

Comment: If I do that, my selection will be gone.